# Visual Studio 2013 update 5 with Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 professioanl update 5, and I have new TFS server 2015 with Default collection only.
From this VS, I've connected to this server TFS 2015, and when I press on "Create Team Project" I got an error

[image]

How can I create a New Team project using 2013 on TFS 2015 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever since TFS has been released, you can only create a new team project with the version that is at least the same as the TFS server. In your case you'll need to be running Visual Studio 2015.

The [Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) will be enough, I haven't installed an express edition in ages, but I suspect that even [Visual studio 2015 express for Desktop](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) will do the trick.